# Model is incompatible with FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, model, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I'm new in Angular, I made an API POST with a model, but that model isn't compatible with my `FormGroup`, and I don't understand how to set up the `FormGroup`. I guess, I have to put something so that the variables are not null or undefined.

My FormGroup:

```
NormaForm = new FormGroup({
  codSector: new FormControl<number>(0, [Validators.required]),
  numNorma: new FormControl<number>(0, [Validators.required]),
  denominacion: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  sumilla: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  contenido: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  tipoNormaId: new FormControl<number>(0, [Validators.required]),
  fechaPublicacion: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
})

get codSector() { return this.NormaForm.get('codSector'); }
get numNorma() { return this.NormaForm.get('numNorma'); }
get denominacion() { return this.NormaForm.get('denominacion'); }
get sumilla() { return this.NormaForm.get('sumilla'); } 
get contenido() { return this.NormaForm.get('contenido'); } 
get tipoNormaId() { return this.NormaForm.get('tipoNormaId'); } 
get fechaPublicacion() { return this.NormaForm.get('fechaPublicacion'); }
```

My form (is somewhat long, so I'll just put the beginning):

```
<form [formGroup]="NormaForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit_crear_norma(this.NormaForm.value)">
  <div class="px-1 py-1 mb-3 wrap-horizontal-filter">
    <div  class="pb-1" fxLayout fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">

      <div fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
        <div fxFlex="50%" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutAlign.lt-sm="stretch" fxLayoutGap="10px">
          <label fxFlex="30%">Código de sector:</label>
          <input fxFlex type="number" class="form-control mb-2" formControlName="codSector"/>
        </div>
```

My model:

```
export interface NormaPost {
  "codSector": number,          
  "numNorma": number,             
  "denominacion": string,  
  "sumilla": string,        
  "contenido": string,       
  "tipoNormaId": number,          
  "fechaPublicacion": Date
}
```

The API function:

```
onSubmit_crear_norma(normaPost:NormaPost): void {
      
  this.normaService.postNorma(normaPost).subscribe(resp=>{
    this.nueva_norma = resp;
    console.log(this.nueva_norma)
  }, err => {
    this.toastr.error("Error desconocido");
  });
}
```

Image error in Visual Studio Code:
[image]

> Argument of type 'Partial<{ codSector: number | null; numNorma: number
> | null; denominacion: string | null; sumilla: string | null;
> contenido: string | null; tipoNormaId: number | null;
> fechaPublicacion: string | null; }>' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'NormaPost'.   Types of property '"codSector"' are incompatible.
> Type 'number | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ngtsc(2345) modal-norma-creacion.component.ts(11, 60): Error occurs in the
> template of component ModalNormaCreacionComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As start from Angular 14 which introduces the strict form types](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-typed-forms/),

If you want to implement all the form controls in the Form Group as non-nullable:

1. Get the `NonullableFormBuilder` service from the dependency injection.
2. Create `NormaForm` form group instance with `NonullableFormBuilder` service.

```
constructor(private fb: NonNullableFormBuilder) {}

NormaForm! = FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  this.NormaForm = this.fb.group({
    codSector: [0, { validators: [Validators.required] }],
    numNorma: [0, [Validators.required]],
    denominacion: ['', [Validators.required]],
    sumilla: ['', [Validators.required]],
    contenido: ['', [Validators.required]],
    tipoNormaId: [0, [Validators.required]],
    fechaPublicacion: [new Date(), [Validators.required]],
  });
}
```

3. Well, you don't need to pass the `NormaForm.value` from the view as you can get it in the component.

```
<form [formGroup]="NormaForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit_crear_norma()">

  ...

</form>
```

4. In the `onSubmit_crear_norma` method, get the `this.NormaForm.value` and cast it as `NormaPost` type.

```
onSubmit_crear_norma(): void {
      
    this.normaService.postNorma(this.NormaForm.value as NormaPost).subscribe(resp=>{
      this.nueva_norma = resp;
      console.log(this.nueva_norma)
    }, err => {
      this.toastr.error("Error desconocido");
  });
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jeeuck?file=src/main.ts)